# OpenNLP save a trained model

Tags: java, opennlp

I used `OpenNLP` for `Name Entity Recognition`(NER). They have their own models [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/). But their NER domain is not suitable with myone. So trained my own model using this code

```
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("res/review_train");
            ObjectStream fileStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(fileReader);
            ObjectStream sampleStream = new NameSampleDataStream(fileStream);
            TokenNameFinderModel model = NameFinderME.train("pt-br", "train", sampleStream, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
            nfm = new NameFinderME(model);
```

Here `review_train` is the text file containing trained text.**Problem** is Every time when i run it takes too much time to train the data. Is there any way to save this trained model and reuse it?

Comment: are you adding new training to the existing models by openNLP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save model using this code and reuse without train again and again

```
BufferedOutputStream modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename"));
model.serialize(modelOut);
```

Comment: hi man! is there any way to add new training data to existing models provided by openNLP? ex. is want to add new training data to en-nre-date.bin.